# Can I disable the bootstrap checks in Elasticsearch 5.4?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running Elasticsearch on a non-production RHEL6 server. I only have a regular user account with no root access. I'm in a very locked-down corporate environment so getting root will be time-consuming and I need a work-around.

When I start the process I get these errors:

```
max file descriptors [8192] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
max number of threads [1024] for user [salimfadhley] is too low, increase to at least [2048]
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

Is there a way to make ElasticSearch ignore this error condition and just start up.

I'm fully aware that ignoring errors is normally considered unwise, however on this occasion I just need to get ES up and running so that I can devote my attention to other aspects of this project: Getting the system limits raised will take more time than I currently have available.

Comment: Hi again ;). This is a very technical question about ELS. I doubt that someone here could actually answer to this question unless this person worked on ELS development. You should ask this question to [Elasticsearch Forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/c/elasticsearch) or [Elasticsearch GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) instead.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/bootstrap-checks.html#_development_vs_production_mode) explains how to disable those checks. (hint: bind to localhost instead of an external network interface so you are considered to run in "development" mode)

Comment: I saw that - unfortunately it is running on a server, so binding to localhost might not be that useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@ThomasDecaux is correct that you can technically disable bootstrap. **But you can only disable bootstrap checks sometimes**. Here is when you can disable bootstrap checks:

- configured your `elasticsearch.yml` with `discovery.type: single-node`
- or your N nodes are all using zen discovery on `localhost`

**If you need to run N nodes on N machines as one cluster, then no you can not disable bootstrap checks.**

When you configure your `elasticsearch.yml` to use an external interface and you don't have `discovery.type: single-node` then bootstrap checks can not be disabled. I tried.

I had a machine failing the bootstrap tests but I didn't have sudo permission to fix it. I tried to disable checks by passing [the `-Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/bootstrap-checks.html) to the [Java JVM options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/jvm-options.html) but the bootstrap checks were still enabled.

Here is a github issue from 2018 where the developers say you can't disable bootstrap checks https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/31933 :

> " There is no command line option for disabling bootstrap checks. The
>   es.enforce.bootstrap.checks option is used to enable them when they
>   are disabled due to Elasticsearch not detecting that it is being used
>   in production (single node, only reachable through localhost or using
>   single-node discovery). "

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can!

(I found) this is very dirty, but if you configure `discovery.type` as `single-node`, no bootstrap check will run.

Yes, that means you cannot test a cluster in your laptop.

See https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21655

Comment: You can create a cluster by binding all the nodes with localhost :)

Comment: True, but I think most of people will use Docker for that, with the official elasticsearch image, and this is very not handy at all!

Comment: If you wish to run N nodes on N machines as one cluster, then **no** you can not disable bootstrap checks. If your elasticsearch.yml is set to use an external interface (i.e. not `discovery.type: single-node` and not `localhost` discovery) then bootstrap checks can not be disabled.

Comment: I had a machine failing the bootstrap tests. I tried to disable checks by passing [the `-Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/bootstrap-checks.html) to the [Java JVM options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/jvm-options.html) but the bootstrap checks were still enabled.

Comment: Use debug log to see exactly whats going on